# How to create a List of 3?

Tags: inext

What I´m looking for is a way to create data like the one resulting from the following code:

```
## import packages
library(iNEXT)

#data(spider)
data(ciliates)
str(ciliates)
```

How to create a "List of 3" like the resulting `ciliates` from scratch?

What I have are two .csv-files like the following:

```
species <- c("species_1","species_2","species_3","species_4")
plot.1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
plot.2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0)

MyData.1 <- data.frame(species, plot.1, plot.2)

write.csv(MyData.1, file = "MyData_1.csv")

species <- c("species_1","species_2","species_3","species_4")
plot.3 <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
plot.4 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)

MyData.2 <- data.frame(species, plot.3, plot.4)

write.csv(MyData.2, file = "MyData_2.csv")

read.csv(file = "MyData_1.csv")
read.csv(file = "MyData_2.csv")
```

I hope my question is clear. Otherwise please ask to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is clear. Assuming you're simply asking how to concatenate several dataframes into a `list`, you can use the `list` function, e.g. `list(MyData.1, MyData.2, MyData.2)`. This returns

`[[1]]
    species plot.1 plot.2
1 species_1      0      0
2 species_2      1      0
3 species_3      0      1
4 species_4      0      0`

`[[2]]
    species plot.3 plot.4
1 species_1      0      1
2 species_2      1      0
3 species_3      0      1
4 species_4      1      0`

`[[3]]
    species plot.3 plot.4
1 species_1      0      1
2 species_2      1      0
3 species_3      0      1
4 species_4      1      0`

Let me know if you're looking for something more, and we can go from there!